# Переместить столбцы двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, c

Есть матрица `double x[n][n]`. Как найти в ней все столбцы, состоящие только из нулей и переместить их в конец?

Пример:

```
 0 1 0 1
 0 1 0 2
 0 1 0 3
 0 1 0 4
```

Результат:

```
 1 1 0 0
 1 2 0 0
 1 3 0 0
 1 4 0 0
```

Мысли следующие:

```
void null_colls(double **a, n)
{
  int i,j,k;
  int b[n]; /* Массив хранит нули, если в нем встретится 1, значит этот столбец матрицы нулевой */

  /* Заполнить массив нулями */
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
     b[i] = 0;
  }

  /* Искать нулевые столбцы */
  for(j=0; j<n; i++)
  {
    flag = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if( a[i][j] != 0.0 ) flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    if( flag == 0 ) { b[j] = 1; }
  }

  /* Поменять 2 столбца местами */
  k = n-1;
  for (j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
    /* Если i-ый столбец нулевой, то меняем местами с последним */
    if(b[j] == 1 && b[k] != 1)
    {
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        a[i][j] = a[i][k];
        a[i][k] = 0.0;
      }
      k--;      
    }
    else if(b[j] == 1 && b[k] == 1)
    {
      k--; 
    }
  }
}
```

Но есть ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define n 4

 int main(void){
    int k, r, s, i, j;

    double x[n][n] = {
        { 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 2 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 3 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 4 }
    };

    //исходная матрица
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            printf("%.0lf ", x[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    // процесс обработки
    for(k = n, j = 0; j < k; ++j){
        for(s = i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            s += (x[i][j] != 0);

        if(s == 0){
            for(i = j; i < (k - 1); ++i){
                for(r = 0; r < n; ++r)
                    x[r][i] = x[r][i + 1];
            }
            for(r = 0; r < n; ++r)
                x[r][k - 1] = 0.0;
            --k;
        }
    }

    // обработанная матрица
    putchar('\n');
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            printf("%.0lf ", x[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```